Spark Job failure while task serialization
Sometimes when we execute the job in spark standalone cluster we get the following error.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task serialization failed: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: ./tmp/blockmgr-8909f7dc-4e05-4ca9-88b2-4a19a159b10c/0c
java.nio.file.NoSuchFile

Exception: /tmp/blockmgr-8909f7dc-4e05-4ca9-88b2-4a19a159b10c/0c
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:384)
    at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:674)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockManager.getFile(DiskBlockManager.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskStore.remove(DiskStore.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.removeBlockInternal(BlockManager.scala:1979)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.org$apache$spark$storage$BlockManager$$doPut(BlockManager.scala:1462)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1499)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.putIterator(BlockManager.scala:1354)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.putSingle(BlockManager.scala:1843)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.writeBlocks(TorrentBroadcast.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.<init>(TorrentBroadcast.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcastFactory.newBroadcast(TorrentBroadcastFactory.scala:34)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.BroadcastManager.newBroadcast(BroadcastManager.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.broadcast(SparkContext.scala:1529)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.submitMissingTasks(DAGScheduler.scala:1513)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.submitStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1329)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleJobSubmitted(DAGScheduler.scala:1271)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2810)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2791)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)

    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2672)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2608)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.submitMissingTasks(DAGScheduler.scala:1523)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.submitStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1329)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleJobSubmitted(DAGScheduler.scala:1271)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2810)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2791)

On executing again the job becomes successful but would like to know if anyone can help why it occurs
